# How can I reset a autoincrement sequence number in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

How to update table sqlite_sequence in Ormlite ? I just need update seq. How can I get that table via ORMLite ?

**EDIT**

I can't find ORLite tool to do this, so instead I use simple sqlite query. In my class extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper I use SQLiteDatabase to make that update.

**EDIT2 ;)**

In my project I persist class Lesson and class WeekDefinition.

```
class Lesson{
    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int id;
    ...
}

class WeekDefinitions{
    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField(foreign=true, columnName="lesson_id")
    private Lesson lesson;
    ...
}
```

Now , when I add new lessons, id is increment. For example

```
id = 1 Math
id = 2 English
id = 3 Medicine
```

and in weekDefinition :

```
id = 1 lesson_id = 1  nr = 20
id = 2 lesson_id = 1  nr = 22
id = 3 lesson_id = 2  nr = 32
...
id = 12 lesson_id = 3  nr = 3
```

SQLite add this row into sqlite_sequence ( when use autoincrement )

```
rowId = 1   name = lesson         seq = 3
rowId = 2   name = weekDefinition seq = 12
```

Now, I delete all rows from tables Lesson and WeekDefinition. Lesson and WeekDef are empty after that, but sqlite_sequence is still the same. And this is problem because id in table lesson start from value 4 ( seq from sqlite_sequence for lesson and add 1 ) :

```
id = 4 Math
id = 5 English
id = 6 Medicine
```

and weekDefinition

```
id = 13 lesson_id = 1  nr = 20
id = 14 lesson_id = 1  nr = 22
id = 15 lesson_id = 2  nr = 32
```

and for lesson id = 4 , Math i should get weekDefinitios, but in weekDefinitions lessons_id has value only from 1 to 3
And this is my problem. I need "reset" sqlite_sequence table ( or there is better solution ?)

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question and provide more details Bandzio.  I have no idea what you are asking here.  What is "sqlite_sequence"?  Are you trying to get a sequence number from a table in the database only?  So the object you are persisting _only_ has a generated id?

Comment: Bandzio, you really should accept one of the answers;  Both are good and have been around for over 6 months

Answer (score 28):

Building on Marcos Vasconcelos' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5600067/641833):

```
UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = (SELECT MAX(col) FROM Tbl) WHERE name="Tbl"
```

This query will set `seq` to the largest value in the `col` identity column in the `Tbl` table, so there is no risk of violating constraints.

Comment: @byteC0de Did you replace col with the column name you want to update and Tbl with the table name you want to update?

Answer (score 13):

Inside your .db file there's an table called `sqlite_sequence`

Each row has two columns
`name` which is the name of the table
`seq` a integer indicating the current last value at this table

You can update it to `0`

But beware if your table use this id as the unique identifier.

Answer (score 7):

```
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET SEQ= 'value' WHERE NAME='table_name';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to issue general database commands in ORMLite, you can use the `updateRaw` method.  See the [javadocs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#updateRaw%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29).  There is also `executeRaw` for other commands.

```
lessonDao.updateRaw("delete from 'lesson';");
lessonDao.updateRaw("delete from sqlite_sequence where name='lesson';");
weekDefinitionDao.updateRaw("delete from 'weekdefinition';");
weekDefinitionDao.updateRaw(
    "delete from sqlite_sequence where name='weekdefinition';");
```

You could also drop and recreate the table as well:

```
TableUtils.dropTable(WeekDefinition.class);
TableUtils.dropTable(Lesson.class);
TableUtils.createTable(Lesson.class);
TableUtils.createTable(WeekDefinition.class);
```

I think the real question is why is your application depending on this database internal number?  It really shouldn't care.

- How about not displaying the number at all so it can be 1 or 1001 and your application won't matter?
- You could also never remove the lessons at all but maybe add a hidden boolean field.  So if they get re-added, the hidden field could be set to false and `Math` would still be at id #1.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in  my database : (I Set the id  before one, then after deleting one row, when I add new data row again, the auto increment serial remain ok  ) :

```
 public void  updateSerialNumber ( long memberId){
        String query = "UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET SEQ= '"+(memberId-1)+"' WHERE NAME='"+ReportBigHelper.TABLE_MEMBER+"'";
        database.execSQL(query);
    }
```