# Delete all data from the database and indexes

Tags: android, database

To remove the statistics from my database I use:

```
ourDatabase.delete (DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
```

But I wanted to base indexes were created at one.
How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I reset a autoincrement sequence number in sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586269/how-can-i-reset-a-autoincrement-sequence-number-in-sqlite)

Comment: What did you find, that is, to ORMlite do not know if it is compatible.

Comment: It is not specific to ormlite. In Android, SQLite does create a table **sqlite_sequence** inside database file to keep track of *auto_increment* values. So just reset that table and you are good to go

Comment: OK I use: `ourDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" + DATABASE_TABLE + "'");` and it works. Delete this topic.