# ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils'

Tags: django

Recently, I upgraded the version of Django framework from **`2.0.6`** to **`3.0`** and suddenly after calling `python manage.py shell` command, I got this exception:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (/path-to-project/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/**init**.py)

**Full trace:**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/path-to-project/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/path-to-project/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/path-to-project/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/path-to-project/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/path-to-project/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/path-to-project/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/corsheaders/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .checks import check_settings  # noqa: F401
  File "/path-to-project/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/corsheaders/checks.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.utils import six
```

**Similar Questions:**

I read this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191180/getting-error-cannot-import-name-six-from-django-utils-when-using-django-3-0) and this [django-3.0](/questions/tagged/django-3.0), [release note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/) , but those resources couldn't help me.

Comment: You use a package `corsheaders` that still uses a module that was removed.

Comment: @MohammadMasoumi Basically, remove explicit statements like `from django.utils import six` if you have them in your code, and then systematically bump the versions of all packages in `requirements.txt` that complain about this. In my case I had to also bump `django-nested-admin` and `djangorestframework`.

Comment: If you are working with a package that hasn't been updated to work with django 3.0, you can fix this with a [simple patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59710132/10746224).

Comment: Hi Mohammad, Does your problem being solved? What is the proper solution?

Comment: Hi @MostafaGhadimi, as @WillemVanOnsem mentioned, I solved it by upgrading the ``corsheaders`` package. I appreciate you for sharing your experience as an answer here, I hope it'll solve someone's problem.

Comment: check for install six and django-compress last version

Comment: My issue was with `django-tag-parser`, make sure you install the latest version.
I have installed `django-tag-parser==3.2` and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The **Django 3.0.0** release notes specify that certain [private Python 2 compatibility APIs were removed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#removed-private-python-2-compatibility-apis). Among those was `django.utils.six`.

For this error specifically, @WillemVanOnsem noted that the module `corsheaders` was referencing this module.

For others encountering this same thing, looking at the file path on the last line of the stack trace can help with identifying the problematic module. Another example of this I've seen is:

```
...
File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/parler/utils/conf.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/__init__.py)
```

The module causing the issue, in this case, was `parler`. I hope this helps any others who encounter this issue.

Comment: Please install lower Django version, in my case I installed Django-2.1.4.

Comment: @smartworld-dm Downgrading Django version will solve the issue, but you can't stay in older versions always, *Change Is Inevitable*

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Actually my project was using Django-2.1.4 and Django 3.0.0 was accidentaly installed.

Comment: Lower Django solve mi problem. I will wait until the modules update their versions.

Comment: You also solve this upgrading the django-cors-headers package `pip install --upgrade django-cors-headers` as sugested by @aryan-jadon on [Github](https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django-web-demo/issues/14).

Comment: If there are any packages that are still using six then this is the best work around I have found 
Install this library: django-utils-six 2.0 for Django >= 3.
`pip install django-utils-six`

Answer (score 98):

### Why this error/exception?

From [django-3.0](/questions/tagged/django-3.0)[release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#removed-private-python-2-compatibility-apis),

> **`django.utils.six`** - Remove usage of this vendored library or switch to [six](https://pypi.org/project/six/).

means, **`django.utils.six`** module was removed from **[django-3.0](/questions/tagged/django-3.0) onwards**.

### My codebase isn't using "`django.utils.six`" module, then why this error?

This import error could be raised because of two reasons,

1. Most importantly, **any of your installed packages are using the `django.utils.six` module**
2. or maybe your codebase using the **`django.utils.six`** module

**NOTE:** Most of the time the first reason is the villain

### How can I identify which package is causing the error/exception?

The easy way is, **look into your last few lines of error traceback**, and it will tell you which package is causing the exceptions.

### Examples

#### Corsheaders

In this example, [**`corsheaders`**](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) module caused the the import error

```
  File "/path-to-project/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/corsheaders/__init__.py", line 1, in 
    from .checks import check_settings  # noqa: F401
  File "/path-to-project/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/corsheaders/checks.py", line 7, in 
    from django.utils import six
```

#### Example-2

In this example, [**`jsonfield`**](https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonfield/) module caused the the import error

```
  File "d:\production\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\jsonfield\fields.py", line 21, in 
    from .encoder import JSONEncoder
  File "d:\production\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\jsonfield\encoder.py", line 2, in 
    from django.utils import six, timezone
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (d:\production\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\__init__.py)
```

#### Example-3

In this example [**`parler`**](https://pypi.org/project/django-parler/) module caused the import error

```
...
File "/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/parler/utils/conf.py", line 10, in 
    from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/__init__.py)
```

#### Example-4

In this example [**`django_mysql`**](https://pypi.org/project/django-mysql/) module caused the import error

```
  File "/home/jerin/.virtualenvs/webscraperio/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_mysql/checks.py", line 9, in 
    from django_mysql.utils import collapse_spaces
  File "/home/jerin/.virtualenvs/webscraperio/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_mysql/utils.py", line 17, in 
    from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six'
```

## What is the solution?

If the error raised because of some third-party packages like [**`django-cors-headers`**](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/),[**`django-jsonfield`**](https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonfield/), etc **upgrade the corresponding package versions to latest versions**. If you are already using the latest version, report an issue with the developer.

If the error raised because from your codebase, use [**six**](https://pypi.org/project/six/) package instead of **`django.utils.six`** module

Comment: One simple solution is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65067103/cloudinary-django-django3-does-not-support-django-utils-six-fix/76316763#76316763

Answer (score 71):

Install this library: `django-utils-six` 2.0 for Django >= 3.

```
pip install django-utils-six
```

Answer (score 31):

First, install six from pip

```
pip install six
```

Second, call six

```
from six import text_type
```

For me works, I have Django 3.0.4

Comment: This worked for me as I was using six in my code.

Answer (score 24):

As mentioned by Mohammad Masoumi, upgrading the packages will resolve the issue because `corsheaders` is supporting Django 3.0 now.

```
pip install --upgrade django-cors-headers
```

I also upgraded `djangorestframework` and `drf_yasg` to avoid this ImportError.

Answer (score 13):

You need to update the cors headers package:

```
pip3 install six
pip3 install --upgrade django-cors-headers
```

Comment: just downgrading to django==2.2 and just installing six solved the issue for me. Why do we need to upgrade cors-headers ?

Comment: If you upgraded your django version to 3.x you should consider upgrading cors-headers. That is another alternative also.

Answer (score 10):

**Exception:**

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django_celery_beat/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    import timezone_field
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/timezone_field/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from timezone_field.fields import TimeZoneField
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/timezone_field/fields.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/__init__.py)
```

**Solution:**

```
 vi /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/timezone_field/fields.py
```

**Change:**

```
from django.utils import six
```

**To:**

```
import six
```

Comment: Modifying installed packages like this isn't a good idea. If you install the same packages on a new server then you'll get an error again. In this case, a better fix is to upgrade [`django-timezone-field`](https://github.com/mfogel/django-timezone-field/) - version 4.0 added support for Django 3.0.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.

My issue was using:

```
pip install django_taggit==0.22.2
```

I resolved this when I did:

```
pip install django_taggit==1.2.0
```

because that is the latest version.

Comment: This answer could be useful, but it's better as a comment under the original post since other people have already recommended upgrading other packages.

Answer (score 6):

Folks' ideal solution is an **upgrade** and clean usage, but a workaround for folks in dire straits is simple enough.

In `Django` utils create a new file six.py and inside the file put:

```
import six
```

**NOTE:** Not a solution but a workaround for immediate patching

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of libraries and add-ons to Django that use django.utils.six, which of course are now broken. The main one of concern is mysql-connector-python (8.0.18). The simple solution is to use the library external to Django, but the authors of these libraries will need to make their changes (or you could temporarily make the changes yourself....replace django.utils.six with six).

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this issue by installing a higher version of `corsheader` package.

[**`corsheader`**](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) v3.3.0 supports Django 3.0.x

```
django-cors-headers==3.3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

**JSONField Solution**:

I used `jsonfield` and `jsonfiled2` packages. But in both cases, I faced the same error.

My problem solved when I have installed `django-jsonfield` package and uninstall the rest of the packages (related to jsonfield).

```sh
# In case you have installed the following packages, otherwise ignore them.
pip uninstall jsonfield
pip uninstall jsonfield2

pip install django-jsonfield
```

**Usage**:

```py
from django.db import models
from jsonfield import JSONField

class ModelName(models.Model):
    json_field = JSONField()
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. Let me tell you how I solved it (fortunately it was simple to do).

### So, what's going on?

You have to pay attention to the traceback Django is telling you (*pro tip*: start from the bottom):

```
  File "/path-to-project/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/corsheaders/checks.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (/path-to-project/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/init.py)
```

It tells you two important things:

1. What's going on: `ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils'`
2. Where it's happening: `/lib/python3.7/site-packages/corsheaders/checks.py", line 7, in <module>`

It is first telling you it cannot import the `six` module from `django.utils`, which is quite logical since Django has [deprecated the module in Django 3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.0/#removed-private-python-2-compatibility-apis).

Now you may ask:

- *but hey, I wasn't using that module!!*
- You're right, but a dependency was :)
- *Which dependency?*
- I'm glad you asked...

This one ==> `/lib/python3.7/site-packages/corsheaders/checks.py`, **`corsheaders`** was importing the module here: `from django.utils import six` in `checks.py` (in line 7).

### What's the solution?

This issue is generally solved by [updating the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183672/how-do-i-update-a-python-package) that created the problem in the first place. They probably removed that import and replaced it with something else, if necessary.
Go to the command line and type:

```
pip install corsheaders -U
```

### What generated the problem?

Django stopped supporting Python 2. Since `django.utils.six` [provided](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/utils/six.py) "*Utilities for writing code that runs on Python 2 and 3*", it was not longer necessary to support this module, so it was deprecated in Django 3.

Answer (score 2):

Django six is not available for Django versions higher than django2, so a quick fix is to install it via pip:

`pip install django-utils-six`

Then you should be good to go

Answer (score 1):

If the error raised because of some third-party packages and you are already using the latest version, report an issue with the developer. If you did that but you really need a urgent fix, this strategy could make the third party package happy:

```
    
try:
    # six removed since Django 3.0
    from django.utils import six
except ImportError:
    import six
    import sys
    sys.modules["django.utils.six"] = six
    # similarly for any other six sub-module required:
    sys.modules["django.utils.six.moves"] = six.moves


# finally, import the outdated third-party package below:

import outdated_library
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, You just need to delete `tokens.py` file at all
if You have a greater version of Django.
And remove all imports `from .tokens` in other files such as `views.py` as well.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I got this same error from using the package `django-braces`. I had used Conda to install it: `conda install -c conda-forge django-braces`. By default as of the time of this answer (Jan 24, 2023) conda-forge installs version 1.13 of `django-braces`, which gives rise to the "cannot import 'six' from django.utils" error.

To fix it, I did the following:

```
conda remove django-braces
pip install django-braces
```

This removes `django-braces` v1.13 and replaces it with v1.15, which solves the problem. Happy django-ing everyone.