# from django.utils import six Importerror: cannot import name six

Tags: python, django

I am working with Haystack 2.8.1 and django 3.0.1 and python 3.6 , getting that error. Solutions looking for, did not solve it for me.the crash is happening in a file i cannot edit .

[ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193514/importerror-cannot-import-name-six-from-django-utils)
below libraries am using

```
django-admin-tools==0.8.1
django-admin-tools-stats==0.9.0
django-cache-utils==0.7.2
django-crispy-forms==1.8.1
django-haystack==2.8.1
django-jsonfield==1.4.0
django-nvd3==0.9.7
django-qsstats-magic==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.8
lxml==3.4.4
MarkupSafe==0.23
psycopg2==2.8.4
python-dateutil==2.4.2
python-memcached==1.57
python-nvd3==0.13.7
python-slugify==0.0.9
Unidecode==0.4.18
wheel==0.24.0
django-report-builder==6.3.2
djangorestframework==3.11.0
markdown==2.6.6
pinax-eventlog==1.1.1
data-importer==2.3.2
django-registration==3.0.1
django-excel==0.0.10
pyexcel==0.5.7
pyexcel-io==0.5.6
pyexcel-webio==0.0.7
pyexcel-xls==0.5.5
pyexcel-xlsx==0.5.5
texttable==0.8.4
xlwt==1.1.1
openpyxl==2.3.5
django-bower==5.2.0
django-notifications-hq==1.5.0
django-simple-captcha==0.5.12
pysolr==3.6.0
Django==3.0.1
django-mail-queue==3.2.2post1
```

Comment: I posted already, that question doesnt resolve my issue.

Comment: Either your codebase or **any of your installed packages** are using the **`Django<3.0`**

Comment: I suggest you read the accepted answer on that question more carefully: _For others encountering this same thing, looking at the file path on the last line of the stacktrace can help with identifying the problematic module._ If it's happening in a file you cannot edit, it means that the third party package you are using is not compatible with Django 3.