# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.six'

Tags: python, django, daphne

HTTP GET /admin/ 500 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:51425]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\daphne\http_protocol.py", line 180, in process
    "server": self.server_addr,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.six'

Installed Django 3.  Django.utils.six is no longer supported.  Thoughts?

Comment: **`django.utils.six`** module was removed from **`django-3.0`** onwards. Check [this answer to resolve the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59420098/12578202)

Answer (score 7):

Django 3 has removed support for `six`, from the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#removed-private-python-2-compatibility-apis):

> While Python 2 support was removed in Django 2.0, some private APIs weren’t removed from Django so that third party apps could continue using them until the Python 2 end-of-life.
>
> Since we expect apps to drop Python 2 compatibility when adding support for Django 3.0, we’re removing these APIs at this time.
>
> ...
>
> django.utils.six - Remove usage of this vendored library or switch to six.

Comment: django removed support that not answer.. what is alternate solution..?

Comment: Try replacing libs that still use six. In my case I had Whitenoise then upgraded it to whitenoise==5.0.1

Comment: we'd need to fork the repo, edit the code to use just `six` (not `django.utils.siz`), then pip install that repo