# import sixImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' by Django Taggit

Tags: django, django-taggit

Django-taggit not working in Django 3.0,It works fine in previous versions like django-2.2.
Because it depends on six library which is not there in django.utils in 3.0

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

```
pip install django_taggit==1.2.0
```

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59400171/11652661