# Django dbbackups : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.six'

Tags: python, django

I am upgerading my Django app from 1.11 to v3 and I get the following error:
 (python 3.8)

```
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/apps.py", line 15, in ready
    from dbbackup import checks
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/checks.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.utils.six import string_types
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.six'
```

My requirements.txt has the following entry:

```
Django~=3.0
django-dbbackup==3.2.0
django-guardian==2.2.0
django-nose==1.4.5
humanfriendly
requests
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193514/importerror-cannot-import-name-six-from-django-utils

Comment: django-dbbackup doesn’t support Django 3.0 yet. See [this issue](https://github.com/django-dbbackup/django-dbbackup/issues/314). If you are upgrading from Django 1.11 LTS, it might be better to upgrade to Django 2.2 LTS, which will be supported for longer than Django 3.0.

Comment: Thanks.. I figured a hack for this until a stable release for Django 3 is launched:

Navigate into the virtual python env and search for string "django.utils.six"

You will probably get these files if the string is found:
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbbackup/db/*

In all files, replace "django.utils.six" with string "six"