# Getting ImportError on Django3.0.4 while running runserver

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, six

I have been trying to run the latest versionof django3.0.4, but I'm getting error while trying to run the local server. I tried installing the package six eventhough it was already installed.

`pip install six`

current version being used is six-1.14.0

`pip install --upgrade django-cors-headers`

current versio being used is django-cors-headers-3.2.1

```sh
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 76, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/home/username/Documents/Projects/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 125, in get_package_libraries
    "trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e)
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'six'
```

Would really appreciate if someone can explain the problem with this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193514/importerror-cannot-import-name-six-from-django-utils)

Comment: It does in some ways, but what should I do inorder to remove this problem, I've tried downgrading django to 2.1.4, but failed