# AttributeError: module 'six' has no attribute 'memoryview' occurs when configuring django database for django-mssql

Tags: python, django, django-mssql, django-mssql-backend

My Django is the latest version, python3.8. I want to configure the database for sql server 2008 R2, so I install  django-mssql(aka,sqlserver_ado). After running the server, an error occurs:

```
  .........
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\base.py", line
 13, in <module>
    from . import dbapi as Database
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\dbapi.py", lin
e 45, in <module>
    from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (C:\Program Files\Pyth
on38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\__init__.py)
```

Following this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193514/importerror-cannot-import-name-six-from-django-utils),

I open "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\dbapi.py" and change "`from django.utils import six`" to "`import six`" , as well as upgrading the six module to latest version.

And this time another Error raised:

```
......
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 20
7, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 11
1, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in impor
t_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\base.py", line
 13, in <module>
    from . import dbapi as Database
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\dbapi.py", lin
e 750, in <module>
    Binary = six.memoryview
AttributeError: module 'six' has no attribute 'memoryview'
```

I check the six module, and yes, it doesn't include a single word named "memoryview". But why the dbapi.py include the code "`Binary = six.memoryview`"? And I search "six.memoryview" on Google.So many results but I can't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `django-mssql` package hasn't been updated in years, and will not work with any currently supported version of Django. The package you will want to use for current versions of Django is `django-mssql-backend`:

https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql-backend/

This package supports both Django 2.2, and Django 3.0, the currently supported versions as of this writing.

Comment: I have been avoiding using django-mssql-backend because I know little about ODBC ....but finally I have to face it again....Well, at least I know django-mssql is outdated and won't waste more time on it, thank you.