# Android room - How to clear sqlite_sequence for all table

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

If user logout from the app, i'm clearing data from tables one by one using

```
@Query("DELETE FROM tableName")
```

Then i'm trying to clear the sqlite_sequence for all table one by one using below code.

```
database = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DatabaseMeta.DB_NAME)
        .build(); 
database.query("DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = ?", new Object[]{"tableName"})
```

Unfortunately clearing `sqlite_sequence` is not working. So if the user login again, then the starting rowId is not created from 1.

Is there any other way to do this? I trying to clear whole DB and will add the new entries once the user login again.

Comment: I have the same issue, Did you get any solution

Comment: @byteC0de No. Haven't got any. Seems we can't clear 'sqlite_sequence' with Room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears Room Database doesn't support editing the sqlite_sequence table, either through a DAO or through a raw query.  Instead, here's how I worked around this problem (Kotlin):

```
class NonRoomDb(context:Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION) {
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {}
    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {}
}

fun resetPointer(context:Context, tableName:String) {
  val nonRoomDb = NonRoomDb(context)
  nonRoomDb.writableDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='$tableName';")
  nonRoomDb.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298431/8094213), you can use the next query for that:

```
UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = (SELECT MAX(col) FROM Tbl) WHERE name="Tbl"
```

> This query will set seq to the largest value in the col identity column in the Tbl table, so there is no risk of violating constraints.

Comment: I agree that above sql statement will update 'seq' value in "sqlite_sequence". But this is not working with Android Room. I'm clearing the table and updating the "sqlite_sequence" table, but after all this a new entry is not getting rowId as 1. Increment happening with the old max rowId.

Comment: Same problem being described here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573731/not-able-to-update-sqlite-sequence-table-using-roomdatabase-query Any idea why we are not able to update `sqlite_sequence` using Room database?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite unexpected behavior but Android Room not providing Access to other tables that was not created by classes. If you like to access it, you should use `SQLiteDatabase` as i got best reference [by Martin Zeitler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53764393). after log time my problem solved.

```
SupportSQLiteDatabase supportSQLiteDatabase = DatabaseRoomClassObj.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteDatabase supportSQLiteDatabase1 = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(supportSQLiteDatabase.getPath(), null, null);
supportSQLiteDatabase1.execSQL("delete from sqlite_sequence");
```

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way I found to delete all tables from `sqlite_sequence` is executing

`DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence`

with `SupportSQLiteDatabase`'s `execSQL()` method in your `RoomDatabase.Callback`'s overridden `onOpen` method (or `onCreate` method).

Like this:

```
private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence");
        // Your code...
    }
};
```